# How to increment a value in one sibling component from another on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components, increment

```
function LeagueBadge(props) {
    return (
        <img src={props.badgeUrl} alt="missing alt text" />
    );
}

class LeagueInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            amountOfPlayers: null,
            rpPerSecond: null,
            rpCost: null,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>{this.props.name} players: {this.props.amountOfPlayers}</h4>
                <h4>RP per second: {this.props.rpPerSecond}</h4>
                <h4>RP cost: {this.props.rpCost}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class League extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <LeagueBadge badgeUrl={this.props.badge} />
                <LeagueInfo name={this.props.name} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1>Players</h1>
                <League name="Bronze" badge={ require('./bronze.png') }></League>
                <League name="Silver" badge={ require('./silver.png') }></League>
                <League name="Gold" badge={ require('./gold.png') }></League>
                <League name="Platinum" badge={ require('./platinum.png') }></League>
                <League name="Diamond" badge={ require('./diamond.png') }></League>
                <League name="Master" badge={ require('./master.png') }></League>
                <League name="Challenger" badge={ require('./challenger.png') }></League>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to be able to click at the image which is the LeagueBadge component and increment the value of amountOfPlayers in their sibling LeagueInfo. I've googled react siblings communication already and only found examples with input tag and onChange but here I want img tag or button and onClick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could lift the state for `amountOfPlayers` up into your `<Leauge />` component, so that:
- updates can be triggered from `<LeagueBadge />` 
- and, that state can be passed down to your `<LeagueInfo />` component

This would allow you to share and synchronize state between the `<LeagueInfo />` and `<LeagueBadge />` siblings as you require.

To do this, you would need to add an `onClick` callback to `<LeagueBadge />` which is fired when the `img` element is clicked. In the `<Leauge />` render method, you could provide the logic that increments the `amountOfPlayers` state in `<Leauge />`. When the `amountOfPlayers` is incremented, and `setState` is called (in `<Leauge />`), this would in turn cause your `<Leauge />` component to re-render itself (and children/siblings). Because the updated value for `amountOfPlayers` is passed  as a prop to `<LeagueInfo />` component, this updated value would be rendered in `<LeagueInfo />`- effectively achieving what you're after.

Something like this might work for you:

```
class LeagueBadge extends Component {
    render() {

    // Add props.onClick callback to trigger click event in <League /> 
    // component
    return (
        <img src={this.props.badgeUrl} alt="missing alt text" 
             onClick={() => this.props.onClick()} />
    );
    }
}

class LeagueInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // amountOfPlayers: null, // This is not needed, as it's supplied by props
            rpPerSecond: null,
            rpCost: null,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>{this.props.name} players: {this.props.amountOfPlayers}</h4>
                <h4>RP per second: {this.props.rpPerSecond}</h4>
                <h4>RP cost: {this.props.rpCost}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class League extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {

        this.setState({
            amountOfPlayers : 0
        })
    }

    render() {

        // Locally defined function that increments amountOfPlayers and
        // updates state
        const incrementAmountOfPlayers  = () => {
            this.setState({ amountOfPlayers : 
            this.state.amountOfPlayers + 1 })
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <LeagueBadge badgeUrl={this.props.badge} 
                             onClick={ () => incrementAmountOfPlayers() } />
                <LeagueInfo name={this.props.name} amountOfPlayers={ this.state.amountOfPlayers } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: for now I only copypasted your solution, but it shows me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" in `<img src={props.badgeUrl} alt="missing alt text" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()} />`  PS. I fixed it by removing `this.` from the second props

Comment: @Megoh have just updated - you should be able to copy this in now

Comment: not sure if I need a class there. Maybe just function will be enough for the future

Comment: @Megoh you mean for the `<LeagueBadge  />` component? Let me know if you'd like me to update that answer to make that a functional component

Comment: I've already made LeagueBadge a functional component and removed `this.` from the 2nd props to make it work. Thanks a lot, I'm so happy to have it solved after so many days.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your state in the league component and pass the function responsible to change it to LeagueBadge like:

```
class League extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            amountOfPlayers: null,
        };
    }
    handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
       return {amountOfPlayers: prevState.amountOfPlayers + 1}
    })
  }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <LeagueBadge badgeUrl={this.props.badge} incrementPlayers={this.handleClick}/>
                <LeagueInfo name={this.props.name} amountOfPlayers={this.state.amountOfPlayers}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


function LeagueBadge(props) {
    return (
        <img src={props.badgeUrl} alt="missing alt text" onClick={this.props.incrementPlayers}/>
    );
}
```

use `this.props.amountOfPlayers` in your Info component.

Comment: I will check your solution as well and upvote if it works. It works, however it shows null instead of 0 at the beginning, but it's not a big deal.